# Is preferred candidate polling useful in predicting the likelihood of a candidate winning the primaries?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, primaries, polling

I've heard repeatedly that Donald Trump is the front-runner for the Republican party presidential primaries when measured by polling for preferred candidate of republican voters, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationwide_opinion_polling_for_the_Republican_Party_2016_presidential_primaries) backs that claim up.

However, I suspect that Donald Trump may not win the primaries, because while he has a large number of people who are strongly favourable to him, there's an even larger number of people who are strongly unfavourable to him.

I suspect that if polling measured what proportion of party voters had an overall positive, neutral, or only mildly negative attitude towards a given candidate, Trump wouldn't fare as well as other candidates.

My question is: Is polling for a party member's number 1 favourite candidate a useful way of predicting how likely a candidate is to win the primary? If not, what other polling is publicly available that can predict how likely a candidate is of winning the primary?

(Note: I'm not trying to ask who will win the Republican primary - I think that as of October 2015, the field is far too open to make predictions)

Comment: The concept of a "ceiling" is mentioned in [Does Donald Trump Have A Ceiling?](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/does-donald-trump-have-a-ceiling/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primaries are a conventional single-vote election. The voters in the primary can not express disagreement with a particular candidate except by voting for a different one. That means the current prognosis system - asking potential voters who they prefer the most out of all available candidates - is a pretty good indicator.

But remember that in many (not all) states, the Republican party uses the same winner-takes-all system which the actual presidential election uses ([list of states by republican primary delegation system](http://www.thegreenpapers.com/P08/R-DSVE.phtml)). That means when you look at *nation-wide* polling results, you don't get a prognosis which is as reliable as when you look at the results of all individual states, consider how their delegation systems work, and build a prognosis based on the delegates each state is expected to send.

Also keep in mind that primaries (especially closed primaries where only party supporters can vote) have a tactical component. The parties don't just try to find *their* favorite candidate, but also the candidate who has the best chance to beat the candidate of the other party. To win the crucial swing-states you need a candidate who appeals to the swing-voters. A highly polarizing candidate who is a hardliner for the party doctrine might be popular within the party but not that popular with independent voters. This might prevent tactically-minded party members to vote for that person during the primaries. When you ask someone "who would you prefer as a president?" and "who will you vote for in the primaries?", the answers might be different.

So when you read *any* opinion polls in the media, carefully look at what *exactly* the question was.